# With the instagram api, is it necessary to acquire the permission "public_contents" to use instagram media which other users posted?

Tags: api, permissions, instagram

With the instagram api,
is it necessary to acquire the permission "public_contents" to use instagram media which other users posted?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot fetch your feed (post by other users you follow). It was possible in the past, but not now...

See change log (Deprecation of `/users/self/feed`) https://www.instagram.com/developer/changelog/

Comment: You mean I need the permission? or it's impossible?